# Deadlifts:Which is the best stance: normal or wide?

Tags: strength, bodybuilding, strength-training, deadlifts, powerlifting

If you had to do one,the normal shoulder width or a sumo stance or something else, which one would you do for general strength training?I have noticed that glutes activation is more in the wide stance but overall I can life more weight in the conventional way.

Comment: Why do we always have to pick one or the other? When in doubt, variation! Neither can be unambiguously better or worse.

Comment: Yeah,I am thinking of doing like 2 extra sets of sumos after my normal DL sets,but then again if I knew which exercise was best for some reason,I'd focus more on that.

Comment: This is like asking what is better for your car: Changing the engine oil or servicing the brakes? Different requirements require different approaches.

Comment: Do 1 week sumo the other week conventional and repeat... just like how anyone would do. They carry over to each other.

Comment: I thought Scott Herman had a nice overview of sumo vs conventional with pros and cons: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8Svfg654oA&t=268s

Answer (score 3):

Moving past the obvious **"it depends"** answer, please consider the origins of sumo deadlifts. Now consider the physiology involved. Putting these two things together, we get an answer: **"the best stance" depends on your specific body measurements first and foremost.**

How long are your legs, how short/long are your arms? How do your limbs stack up against your torso? How deep do you have to squat to grab onto a barbell and keep a neutral back? These questions will inform the best stance for *your* body.

But don't forget that variety is key: after doing sumo for a long period of time, a conventional deadlift may become better temporarily just to shake up the routine.